# Update Most Recent Record, with Date and Time in two columns, Time Dependent on Date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I need to select the most recent record by date and time. The date and time are in two separate columns. I can select the max on time in the where clause. Is the best way to get the max of time by date to group by max date, and then select the max time in the where clause?

Test Table
SeqNo   PEOPLE_ID   FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   STATUS  REVISION_DATE   REVISION_TIME

1   1280    Justin  Bonnor  Yes 2008-03-26 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 17:21:25.000

2   83801   Aaron   Odem    Yes 2013-04-18 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 14:23:43.897

3   83811   Sonja   South   No  2014-12-10 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 12:41:67.032

4   83811   Sonja   South   No  2014-12-10 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 16:58:34.060

5   86221   Bryanna Parson  No  2014-12-10 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 16:58:23.480

6   88294   Jaclyn  Velmer  No  2016-04-14 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 15:05:51.427

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could order by both of those columns and select top 1

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TestTable ORDER BY RevisionDate DESC, RevisionTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, so would I just put the select in the subquery after the where clause? where SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TestTable ORDER BY RevisionDate DESC, RevisionTime DESC

Comment: @ERPise I don't understand what you're asking.